# How to upload the image into folder

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I need to push the image into a folder, here image will generated in for loop according to my query, for each and every loop in need push the `$img` to a specific folder.

If it's possible..? Kindly give some solution.

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $sql_sub = select_query("select DESPHOT from  photo where photoid = ".$i."");
    $img = $sql_sub[0][0]->load();

    header("Content-type: image/pjpeg");
    echo $img;
}

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [save BLOB image to disk from database in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160406/save-blob-image-to-disk-from-database-in-php)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160406/save-blob-image-to-disk-from-database-in-php). both question and its answers will help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needs to use `file_put_contents` function for it.

Try

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $sql_sub = select_query("select DESPHOT from  photo where photoid = ".$i."");
    $img = $sql_sub[0][0]->load();

    $target_folder = 'test';
    $filename = $i.'.jpg';

    $new_saved = file_put_contents($target_folder.'/'.$filename, $img);
    echo "Picture save as ".$new_saved;
}

?>
```

**Note** You have to set `0777` permission to `target_folder` if you are using `UNIX/LINUX`.

Above code is not tested. What `$sql_sub[0][0]->load();` do?

Answer (score 1):

Your going to need `move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $newpath)`

more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

```
// set headers
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: $file_type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . $file_size);
```